# How to create base fragments so that child fragment can extend from them to set an adapter in the OnCreateView function?

Tags: android, android-fragments, abstract-class, android-recyclerview

I have an abstract base fragment class that extends from fragment. Monitor list fragment extend from this base fragment. I need to set individual adapters in each fragment because the data in the fragments are different. Problem is, the monitor list fragment only returns 1 fragment with no data?

**In BaseFragment**

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor> objectList;
    private int mColumnCount = 1;


public void setObjectList(String listKey){
        if (getArguments()!=null){
            this.objectList= getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(listKey);


        }

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanseState)
    {
        View view = provideYourFragmentView(inflater,parent,savedInstanseState);
        // Set to recycler view
        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
            }

        }

        return view;

    }
        }
```

**In monitor list fragment**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container,
                savedInstanceState);
        //Set individual adapter
        monitor_list = getObjectList();
        if (v instanceof RecyclerView) {
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v;
            adapter = new MonitorListRecyclerAdapter(monitor_list, this.getContext());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        }
        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the layout I inflated in XML  should be a RecyclerView type.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a abstract method to create Adapter

This may not resolve your problem, but you can do your adapter logic in your sub fragment class, this way will be more clearly

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor> objectList;
    private int mColumnCount = 1;


    public void setObjectList(String listKey){
        if (getArguments()!=null){
            this.objectList= getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(listKey);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanseState)
    {
        View view = provideYourFragmentView(inflater, parent, savedInstanseState);
        // Set to recycler view
        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
            }

            recyclerView.setAdapter(this.createAdapter());
        }

        return view;
    }

    abstract <ViewHolderT extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder, AdapterT extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolderT>> AdapterT createAdapter();
}
```

SubFragmentA

```
public class SubFragmentA extends BaseFragment {
    @Override
    SubAdapterA createAdapter() {
        return new SubAdapterA();
    }

    public static class SubAdapterA extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubViewHolderA> {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public SubViewHolderA onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SubViewHolderA subViewHolder, int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static class SubViewHolderA extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public SubViewHolderA(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

SubFragmentB

```
public class SubFragmentB extends BaseFragment {
    @Override
    SubAdapterB createAdapter() {
        return new SubAdapterB();
    }

    public static class SubAdapterB extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubViewHolderB> {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public SubViewHolderB onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SubViewHolderB subViewHolder, int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static class SubViewHolderB extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public SubViewHolderB(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

If you got multiple ViewHolder Type you can do like this

```
  public static class BaseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView commonTextView;

        public BaseViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //init commonTextView;
        }
    }

    public static class SubViewHolderB extends BaseViewHolder {

        private TextView textViewB;

        public SubViewHolderB(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //init textViewB
        }

        public void bindData(DataModelB data) {
            commonTextView.setText("Common text set Integer data :" + data.intField);
            textViewB.setText("This is Integer :" + data.intField);
        }
    }

    public static class SubViewHolderA extends BaseViewHolder {

        private TextView textViewA;

        public SubViewHolderA(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //init textViewB
        }

        public void bindData(DataModelA data) {
            commonTextView.setText("Common text set String data :" + data.strField);
            textViewA.setText("This is String :" + data.strField);
        }
    }

    public static class DataModelB {
        int intField;
    }

    public static class DataModelA {
        String strField;
    }
```

Comment: I have solved my problem without creating an abstract adapter but I do think an adapter abstract class would help. However, my onBindViewHolder is very different between the two fragments and I'm not sure how to define it in the abstract class.